# Best practices and Design Patterns for iPhone forms?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, forms, core-data, uiwebview

Part of the app I'm making requires the user to fill in a multi-page form, the contents of which will be saved locally (perhaps using Core Data). Are there any best practices for this? This form just includes text fields. I guess the options are UITextFields, or perhaps a UIWebView, with the fields as part of an html form? Are there are any best practices, or design patterns, which are good for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe CoreData is 'oversized' for your needs. A NSDictionnary will be easier to use and much more flexible.

NSDictionnary class offers this methods :
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
– writeToFile:atomically:

Regards,

Comment: Core Data has a tiny footprint, it is highly unlikely that it is oversized for just about anything.

Comment: Marcus, are there standard ways of encrypting Core Data databases? My client would like the data to not be readily accessible to thieves with access to the file system.

Comment: You can use Transform properties as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645007/how-can-i-encrypt-coredata-contents-on-an-iphone

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I will give you one *very important* hint: don't make the controls too small! Give controls ample space! I hate trying to get the iPhone to pick up my finger on a tightly spaced and sized control, only to find I activated the control next to it.