# How to encrypt/decrypt data in Core Data?

Tags: security, core-data, ios, encryption

I am pretty sure Core Data does not have any encryption/decryption features. Is there a tutorial that shows how to "manually" encrypt/decrypt data in Core Data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I encrypt CoreData contents on an iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645007/how-can-i-encrypt-coredata-contents-on-an-iphone)

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data has a binary attribute type that takes instances of NSData. Could you encrypt a file, put the encrypted data into an NSData object, and store it that way?

Comment: I presume that your concerned with securing user data.  That being the case, consider secure removal of the encrypted file (zeroing file data, then deleting):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547517/how-to-securely-erase-a-file-in-ios