# How to securely erase a file in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

When I encrypt a file I want to overwrite its contents, not only delete it.  My intended purpose for this is to securely erase the file.  Is there a way to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file memory mapped and overwrite the data, then delete the file using `NSFileManager`:

```
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: filename];
[file writeData: data];
[file closeFile];
```

Where data is an NSData object

Comment: Can `writeData:` ensure that the data is written to the same area on the flash?

Comment: No. It is basically impossible to write to the same area of flash due to how Flash works.  There is no over-write, instead a new block is allocated, cleared and the unchanging data is copied and the new data also copied.  But the good news is that lacking removal for the flash from the device and rather extensive work the block can not be read.

Comment: So, if your opponent is some professional institutions, the only way to ensure safety is never write plaintext into flash?

Comment: That is really kicking up the paranoia level, are we talking TLAs here? :-) The solution (not available in iOS AFAIK) is to have a custom flash controller chip that erases a flash block as soon as it is unused, yeah that does exist.  The good news: eventually, non-deterministically, the block will be erased and re-used.  There is no residue that can be used to reveal the prior contents.  I have to assume that you are not using NSString or NSData, just cStrings at this level of security.

Comment: Do note that on modern hardware the flash is HW encrypted to there is really no clear text written to it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at English, what dose "TLAs" and "HW" mean?－ －||||

Comment: HW == Hardware.  TLA means "Three Letter Agency" ofter referring to CIA or NSA in the U.S. and in a security context.

Comment: @zaph Will this write random data to the file?

Comment: If the `data` is random data: yes as far as the file system is concerned. But with flash memory the actual block will be inaccessible via the file system but not erased until it is re-used.

Answer (score 1):

Check `NSFileManager`:

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

For example:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *filePath;
NSError *error;
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
     [manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath error:&error];
     if (error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error occured while [removing file]: \"%@\"\n",[error userInfo]);
     }
}
```

For writing in the same file:

```
NSOutputStream *fileStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
[fileStream open];
[fileStream write:&dataBytes maxLength:dataLength];
[fileStream close];
```

Where `dataBytes` is what you want to rewrite with.

Comment: **removeItemAtPath:error:** only remove a file, not overwrite it. It's not safe, use some program you can recovery it.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the old data, open the file using [`[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileHandle/fileHandleForWritingAtPath%3a) (write-only access) or `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:` (read-write access). You can then either use the standard `write` with `[myFileHandle fileDescriptor]`, or use [`[myFileHandle writeData:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/writeData%3a) to write a NSData object.

For deleting the overwritten file, use [`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath%3aerror%3a).

As for *what* to write: I suggest you use a pre-generated a file of a convenient size (multiple of 512) and repeatedly overwrite your old file with the content of your "garbage data" file. Using the random number generator on iOS would only make sense for small files as it's too slow. You also don't gain any (serious) additional security by using random data, so you could as well overwrite the old file with a poem.

Comment: Due to the way flash works this will not over-write the data, just allocate a new flash block (or more) and write to them.

Answer (score -1):

It is NOT necessary to overwrite a file multiple times. This is especially not necessary for Flash memory, as it will use a different block to write the new data anyway. But it's also NOT true for traditional hard drives. It's totally sufficient to oerwrite a file ONCE.