# Swift deleting text files: Are these files actually deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I use the following code to delete file from documents store:

```
class func removeFile(_ itemName:String, fileExtension: String) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    guard let dirPath = paths.first else {
        return
    }
    let filePath = "\(dirPath)/\(itemName)"
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
        print("remove done")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, file is removed from the document directory(I downloaded and checked the container),

The problem occurs when checking app settings on device, I see that the app size is not shrinking when I delete these txt files(They are quite big, like 4,5 mb each, so this 11.7 mb in documents in data comes probably from them)

[image]

My question is:

Does my code really delete the file? Or maybe just delete the reference to it, so the memory cannot be released?

Comment: Take a look a [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547517/how-to-securely-erase-a-file-in-ios)

Comment: When you downloaded and checked the container, how large was it? Did you make sure to refresh the Usage page (the app's usage won't automatically update itself). It should go down after using `removeItem`; it's a fairly standard Unix filesystem. It's possible it's showing you a high-water mark, but I haven't found that to be the case in my experience.

Comment: container wasn't that big, was like 400 kb, this is why it made me wonder why settings are showing such a big number

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe just delete the reference to it, so the memory cannot be released?

This. It is the way most (all?) modern storage works. In the case of iOS you're writing to flash, so the original data will be there until trim is called (IIRC). You cannot even guarantee that a write to that file will overwrite the old data, the storage controller can place the new data anywhere, and this is especially true on flash. This is why the "[NAND attack](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/09/iphone-5c-nand-mirroring-passcode-attack/)" exists.

Comment: Well, so how to prevent from overswelling? Is it any way to keep it size quite fixed whil creating/deleting files?

Comment: Ahh... do what you are doing, if you just want to save space, yes, this is the way to do it. What will happen is that when the drive begins to fill up, the drive controller will start re-using cells. This is one of the reasons drives get slower as they fill up, but not the only one.

Comment: Why settings keep showing documents and data 20mb when the file is allegedly deleted? How can I be sure that file is deleted properly?