# How to encrypt and decrypt transformable properties on os-x application?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, encryption

I am working on a small OS X application that uses core data (sqllite) to store the data.

I am trying to encrypt the data that will be entered by the user. All properties in the entities are transformable.

[I have found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645007/how-can-i-encrypt-coredata-contents-on-an-iphone) here on stackoverflow.

> You can encrypt individual properties in your Core Data model entities by making them transformable properties, then creating an NSValueTransformer subclass which will encrypt and decrypt the data for that property.

Unlucky for me, the author of the answer, @Brad Larson, didn't provide an simple example of how this can be done.

Can anyone post an simple example  - codesnippet of how I can encrypt the user entry and store it in the database encrypted?

Comment: you can check out this url https://github.com/DavidBenko/Encrypted-Core-Data - it's built for iOS but you can tinker with it.

Comment: tip : next time you need to find something regarding a method / specific keyword, start searching on github.com / other opensource code hosting sites, you'll find plenty of implementations there to adapt.