# iPhone:Create Password Protect SQLite database

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, passwords

i am able to create sqlite database using firefox addon and use database in iPhone. Now I want to give the the password to database and used it in my iPhone application. i tried a lot on google to search the proper way yo create password protected database but still no success.

anybody have idea that how can create the password protected sqlite database and how can we use it in iPhone

Comment: See also [Encrypting SQLite Database file in iPhone OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929744/encrypting-sqlite-database-file-in-iphone-os)

Answer (score 3):

Try SQLiteEncrypt.The [SQLiteEncrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/) is an AES encryption embedded SQLite database engine through which you can encrypt and decrypt your SQLite database file. When set a password key into your database file, content is no longer stored in cleartext, so that we achieve the purpose of data protection.

But it is not free.

**Note:** But IT is not for iOS (thanks brad to pointed it out).

*Edit***

For iPhone you can use [SQLCIPHER](http://sqlcipher.net/) which is an open source full database encryption for sqlite.

Comment: It also doesn't work on the iPhone, because it's provided as a .DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no free solution for doing that.
There are some commercial applications,  which allows sqlite database encryption.
Also, there is virtual filesystem support in SQLite, where you can change calls which reads/writes data to SQLite database, however that will require some coding.