# How to protect my database in IOS application (Best way)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, ipad

I'm using SQLite database in my application and I need to protect the SQLite file. What's the best way to protect it?

1. Password protected?
2. DB Encryption?

Comment: may be this [link](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/) helps you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protect an sqlite file on IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457918/protect-an-sqlite-file-on-ios)

Comment: Protection in below scenario.

    1. Unzip MyApp.ipa
    2. With finder click "Show Package Contents"
Here i am able to see My database file. Now how can i prevent it
a) Password protection
b) Encryption

Comment: If you want to protect the data "at rest" encrypt the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proprietary extension for SQLite available that provides encryption:
[The SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html)

If the core data is precious, you should consider obtaining a license.

Alternatively, you can write a [Virtual Filesystem Module](http://www.sqlite.com/vfs.html) which allows you to have code between database engine and file storage and implement some kind of encryption there.