# iOS application secure client side data storage?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, storage, cocos2d-x

I'm developing an iOS game that needs to store the user's score. I don't want the user to be able to modify this score manually. Whats the best practice to doing this?

So far, I've thought of doing symmetrical encryption on the client side but it was brought to my attention that someone can decompile the key which is stored as plain text. I would like to stay away from using web services and keep it all on the client side.

PS - I am developing with Cocos2d-x in C++. If you have any library suggestions to implement your solution, that would be great!

Comment: Visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929744/encrypting-sqlite-database-file-in-iphone-os. It might be helpful for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make the key something that is not stored, such as the id of the current device but history suggests that nothing is ever totally secure, but would it be worth the attacker's while to try that hard?

Comment: I think same. you can try save data securely. but, it can not be impossible to decrypt. there is always a way if you keep key in client too. only finding how data can be decrypted time might be long or short

Answer (score 0):

Simply store it in NSUserDefaults.