# how to locally store a user credit card in an iOS application

Tags: ios, credit-card

I'm developing an iOS application that allows purchasing real physical goods. I'd like to securely store the user's credit card locally on the device for future usage. How would you recommend I do it? Is there any best practise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929744/encrypting-sqlite-database-file-in-iphone-os or you can use sqlcipher http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: havnt done my research, but maybe apple pay is something you could use?

Comment: some of the users don't have apple pay enabled, some have older devices and others might be from countries where apple pay is not supported

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use Apple pay, maybe the keychain should be your choice.